# Equality among multiple numbers?

Tags: terminology

When I have two numbers and they are the same, we can say that they possess "equality".

Let's say I have three or four numbers and they are all the same. What do we call the quality that they possess? Can we say that the three numbers possess "equality" too? What are the other words for this quality?

For example, I have four numbers 4, 4, 4, and 4. What quality do these numbers exhibit?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your pick:

- They are "all equal".
- They are "all equal to each other".
- They are "pairwise equal".
- They are "identical".
- They are "the same".

(The last two are a little vague.)

Comment: I was hoping for peculiar words but thanks anyway.